# Java Rest API playback messages

Tags: java, rest, web-services, playback, message

I have a java rest API which will persists oncoming messages (after some manipulation).

I need another API which playback the messages persisted through the 1st API to the browser. I am using a websocket to push the messages to the browser.

And two more API's to "Pause" and "Stop" the playback.

Basically speaking i am trying to simulate the messages I received (within a given time period), in a fast forwarded manner.

Any idea of how to support "Play", "Pause" and "Stop" functionality?

Thanks

Comment: So, you're trying to recreate a simple Apache Kafka?

Comment: @cricket_007 I am not familiar with Kafka. If that supports my requirements I would definitely use it. I don't want to invent the wheel. :)
Will do some reading on kafka

Comment: I assume you just mean "messages" meaning some text, and "playback" by pulling back some these messages from some "offset" of time and "pause/stop" at some later offset.

Comment: @cricket_007
You are right. 
Messages will contain persisted data.

There will be an api with a playback status ("Play", "Pause", and "Stop").